# iOS swift tableview how can I reload the data when I touch button

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I creat a tableview, and I have a object just like this :

```
public class data: NSObject {
    var name :String = ""
    var number :Double = 0
    var price : Double = 0
    var sum:Double = 0
}
```

I creat a array:

```
var data1 = [data]()
```

and I have a table cell :

```
@IBOutlet var a0: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var a1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var a2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var a3: UITextField!

var data1 : data? {
    didSet {

        var a00 = data1?.name
        var a11 = data1?.number
        var a22 =  data1?.price

        var a33 = a11! * a22!
        a0.text = a00
        a1.text = String(a11!)
        a2.text =  String(a22!)
        a3.text =  String(a33)
    }
}
```

so, how can I reload the data when I touch the button (if I have a button) in my tableview? it's different file, the one is Viewcontroller.swift,the other is tableviewCell.swift, how can I do this?

Comment: You can use delegates, notifications.

Comment: how to use google to find the tutorials

Comment: https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef

Comment: `tableView.reloadData()` ?!

Answer (score 3):

Create a protocol like this:

```
protocol ParentControllerDelegate{
func requestReloadTable()
}
```

In your TableViewCell class:

```
class ProjectCell: UITableViewCell{

var parentDelegate: ParentControllerDelegate?
// And whatever other things you require in the UITableViewCellClass
}
```

Now, when you make your TableViewCell assign your Controller class as the delegate:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableCellID") as! ProjectCell
    cell.parentDelegate = self
    }
```

At this point, you can call protocol method in your Controller object from your UITableViewCell class.
Create an IBAction for your button inside your UITableViewCell class and call:

```
delegate?.requestReloadTable()
```

In the above code, requestReloadTable is a method in your controller class, which you must override when you confirm the controller to the protocol we made earlier:

```
extension HomeController: ParentControllerDelegate{
func requestReloadTable() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
}
```

Comment: i have another question

Comment: how can i understand                    cell.parentDelegate = self                          what is self means??

Comment: Here self refers to `HomeController` and it means that your `HomeController` conforms the `ParentControllerDelegate`. Just like we write `tableView.delegate = self, tableView.dataSource = self` and then write their delegate-datasource methods.

Answer (score 0):

Create IBOutlet for button, which you would-like to update table.
And in action put next code:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

EX:

```
@IBAction func upDateTable(_ sender: Any) {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```